# How to check that IP addess is attched to which eth in Linux Machine?

Tags: linux, shell, suse

Well I use SUSE11 Linux machine, Is there is a single cmd which gives the eth number to which my IP is attched to ?

Ex:

```
<1035 sne-70 [u2see] :/home/u2see/nginrun/log>**ifconfig -a | grep addr**
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:9E:D4:7D:39  
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:9eff:fed4:7d39/64 Scope:Link
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:9E:D4:7D:3A  
          inet addr:192.168.100.70  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:9eff:fed4:7d3a/64 Scope:Link
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:9E:D4:7D:3B  
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:9eff:fed4:7d3b/64 Scope:Link
eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:9E:D4:7D:3C  
          inet addr:**10.19.120.24**  Bcast:10.19.120.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2607:f0d0:1002:11::6/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:9eff:fed4:7d3c/64 Scope:Link
```

My IP is "10.19.120.24" And i need to get the output as eth4 by using single cmd..
What cmd i can use ?

Comment: what it means "My IP is 10.19.120.24"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GNU awk:

```
ifconfig -a |awk -v RS="\n\n" '/inet addr:10.19.120.24 /{print $1}'
```